# Server failing to negotiate handshake with Server on different subnet

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

This issue appears to have just appeared out of nowhere, am I'm looking for some advice on how to troubleshoot. Server_A is 2008R2 and Server_B is 2012R2. Thanks

I have an issue in which Server_A on Subnet_A can't ping Server_B on Subnet_B. However, server_B can ping Server_A. There is a layer 3 switch between the two. Server_A can ping other ip's on Server_B's subnet.

We setup wireshark, and viewed the following:

Server_A --> Server_B:
We see Syn and TCP retransmission traffic only

Server_B --> Server_A:
We see Syn, Ack, echo pings.

Comment: If you see Syn/Ack at ServerB for the ping from ServerA then ServerB is replying. Where's the reply going? What's the destination IP and MAC address of the reply? Can you capture traffic at the switch?